# Reuse parameters from single CSV Dataset for multiple users

Tags: jmeter

I am using "CSV Dataset config" to read a parameter from the specified CSV file. I have set the "Sharing Mode" as all threads. For that Thread Group, I have specified "Number of Threads" as four (for four users). I have set "Recycle on EOF" as "True" (I tried with "False" too, but no difference).

When I start the test, It ran for just one user, read all the data from the CSV file, completed the test and stopped. For the other three users, it did not run at all. My guess is - because the CSV file was closed once the testing for user 1 completed.

I tried using multiple Thread Groups in the same Test Plan and each Test Group had just one user. Even then it did not work.

The expectation is- the same CSV file can be used for multiple users and across different Test Groups. There must be a way to rewind the CSV file either by JSR223 Post Processor or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using [JMeter 5.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter-5.2/) and it is quite hard to tell anything comprehensive without seeing your Test Plan.

My expectation is that you violated [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) somewhere somehow, i.e. you placed CSV Data Set Config inside one Thread Group while it should live at the same level as all Thread Groups

Given

1. The following CSV file stored as `test.csv` in JMeter's "bin" folder:

   ```
   line1
   line2
   line3
   ```
2. And the following [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config):

   [image]
3. 2 [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) set up like:

   [image]
4. You should see that each virtual user in each Thread Group is reading next line from CSV file on each iteration:

   [image]